# How to set value to input HTML tag

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a dropdown box but they have used an input tag, the values are saved inside the `value` attribute, tried passing using the send_keys method it is capturing the value. But when it is moving to the next element the value is gone! it's not saving.

[This is the HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxwyE.png)

How to set the value of the `value` attribute in the input tag.

This is the code i have tried:
[image]
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,partners_drop_down_box_xpath).send_keys("Rentrak")

Comment: Please always provide a minimum reproducible work/code snippets in order to reproduce the error and thus provide you some way around to solve it. 


https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The `send_keys` should work in this case, if possible can you please provide the screenshot of the UI.

**Meanwhile you can use below hack:**
To set the value attribute in an input tag, you can use the `execute_script` method to update the attribute directly.

**Code:**

```
inputValueText = 'Amazon'
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,partners_drop_down_box_xpath)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1]);", element, inputValueText)
    
# To Verify if the value has been set or not, u can use:
print("Set value:", element.get_attribute("value"))
```